# Conversion of a two-dimensional array to three-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Please, give me advice. I have a directory of companies. How to group the names of companies by the first letter. On example: A - Adidas,ASUS... B - BMW,Bentley etc

Array of companies:

```
array() { 
    [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=>  "1" ["name"]=> "Adidas"} 
    [1]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "2" ["name"]=> "ASUS"}
    [2]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "3" ["name"]=> "BMW"}
    [3]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "4" ["name"]=> "Bentley"}
}
```

I want to get:

```
array() {    
   ['A']=> array {[0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=>  "1" ["name"]=> "Adidas"} , [1]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "2" ["name"]=> "ASUS"}}
   ['B']=> array {[2]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "3" ["name"]=> "BMW"},[3]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> "4" ["name"]=> "Bentley"}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array and add the sub-arrays to a new array with the key the first character of `$entry["name"]`

```
$newArray = array_keys(range('A', 'Z')); // ensure a filled array
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    // & ~" " is a shorthand for transforming to uppercase
    $newArray[$entry["name"][0] & ~" ")]][] = $entry; // add $entry to $newArray
}
```